# Wondering why I couldn't just capture the reference of asio::handler_type for the coroutine

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I'm playing with the asio using coroutine, and would like to test how an async function can be called. I have the following code:

```
void async_foo(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, boost::asio::yield_context& yield)
{
    using handler_type = boost::asio::handler_type<decltype(yield), void()>::type;

    handler_type handler(std::forward<handler_type>(yield));
    boost::asio::async_result<decltype(handler)> result(handler);

    auto timer(std::make_shared<boost::asio::deadline_timer>(io_service, boost::posix_time::seconds(1)));
    // the program crashes if I use &handler here
    timer->async_wait([&handler](const boost::system::error_code) {
            std::cout << "enter" << std::endl;
            handler();
            std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
        });
    result.get();

    std::cout << "function finished" << std::endl;

    return;
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::spawn(io_service, [&io_service](boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
            std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
            async_foo(io_service, yield);
            std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
        });
    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

It's weird that if I put &handler in the capture list the execution flow will be messed up and then it hits segmentation fault. But it runs without any problem if I use "handler" instead (then I need a copy in the lambda of course).

Searched around and couldn't find anything related. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tanner very nicely explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26728121/85371):

> - While [`spawn()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/spawn.html)
>     adds work to the `io_service` (a handler that will start and jump to
>     the coroutine), the coroutine itself is not work.  To prevent the
>     `io_service` event loop from ending while a coroutine is outstanding,
>     it may be necessary to add work to the `io_service` before yielding.

If you add an extra trace line after the `run()`:

```
io_service.run();
std::cout << "BYE" << std::endl;
```

Then, run a few times until you're lucky enough to not get the SEGV early, you can see output like the following:

```
hello
enter
done
BYE
```

Indeed, the io_service returns, destructing pending operations/handlers, which also destroys the stack context of the coro¹. Unwinding that stack destructs the (local) variables that live on that stack:

- handler
- result
- timer

And since `timer` is not captured in the completion handler for `async_wait`, the timer is simply canceled, but still tries to invoke the completion handler which now refers to a now-defunct stack variable `handler`.

Copying `handler` apparently² does keep the coro alive.

---

To answer the core question ***"and would like to test how an async function can be called"*** I'd suggest the simpler idiom:

```
void async_foo(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, boost::asio::yield_context& yield)
{
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    timer.async_wait(yield[ec]);
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c58e7b804effadb5)</kbd>**

---

¹ `-fsanitize=address` confirms this
² I know it contains a `weak_ptr` to the coroutine context, so perhaps Asio internally locks that into a `shared_ptr`, not too sure about those implementation details myself

Comment: Thank you a lot for the detailed explanation. I put a testing object with outputs in ctor and dtor, and obviously there is a stack unwinding before the timer gets triggered.