# When must you pass io_context to boost::asio::spawn? (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I was surprised to find that the code below works without passing `io_context` as the first argument to `spawn`. Could somebody please explain why I don't need to pass it in this case, and in what situations you must explicitly pass it. **I'm using Boost 1.75.0**.

```
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  boost::asio::io_context io_context;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_context);

  boost::asio::spawn([&](boost::asio::yield_context yield){ // don't need to pass io_context?!
    std::cout << "started spawn" << std::endl;
    timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    timer.async_wait(yield);
    std::cout << "finished spawn" << std::endl;
  });

  std::cout << "running io_context" << std::endl;
  io_context.run();
  std::cout << "finished running io_context" << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Thanks have specified Boost 1.75.0.

Comment: I would expect that if you don't pass an executor, the continuation will be posted on the executor associated with the object you are awaiting (e.g.  timer.get_executor() in your case).

Comment: That makes sense to me too. But I don't understand why you'd ever need to pass io_context to spawn at all?

Comment: @sbabbi is right; this is what happens when the async operations _inside_ the coro are posted, but it says nothing about where the coro itself is posted, which I think is the question.

Comment: My answer doesn't focus on the title question "When must xxxx". Because the answer is subjective: when you want. I hope my answer highlights why you would want to, or when you wouldn't. When in doubt, I'd _personally_ prefer to be explicit, so I'd even go as far as explicitly passing the fallback executor so it is clear to the reader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asio has added the concept of *associated executors* and *default executors*.

The associated executors is not really new, because the `handler_invoke` protocol already allowed for handler-type specific semantics. However, since the formulation of the executor concept it became more generalized.

Now you can `post` any handler, and it will execute on the associated executor, the executor supplied **or** the default executor. The default executor is ultimately `system_executor{}`.

So

```
post([]{ puts("Hello world"); });
post(system_executor{}, []{ puts("Hello world"); });
```

Both invoke the handler using `system_executor`.

You can bind an associated handler with any handler that doesn't associate one already:

```
post(bind_executor(ex1, []{ puts("Hello world"); }));
post(system_executor{}, bind_executor(ex1, []{ puts("Hello world"); }));
```

Both run the handler on `ex1`, not the fallbacks. Combining the above, you will already expect that this does the same:

```
post(ex1, []{ puts("Hello world"); });
```

*(here, the handler has not associated executor, so `ex1` functions as the fallback)*

### Spawn

Spawn is merely a wrapper that "posts" another type of handler¹. Indeed it is documented to use any associated executor. The implementation reflects this quite readably:

```
template <typename Function>
inline void spawn(BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_ARG(Function) function,
    const boost::coroutines::attributes& attributes)
{
  typedef typename decay<Function>::type function_type;

  typename associated_executor<function_type>::type ex(
      (get_associated_executor)(function));

  boost::asio::spawn(ex, BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(Function)(function), attributes);
}
```

You can see that `get_associated_executor` is called without explicit fallback, defaulting to `system_executor` again.

### Side Notes

In addition

- `spawn` will add a strand where appropriate (this is a reason why providing a concurrency hint when constructing your execution context can make a big difference)
- `spawn` can take a `yield_context` as the first argument, in which case you will effectively run on the same strand (sharing the executor)

---

¹ It's an implementation detail, but it will generally be `boost::asio::detail::spawn_helper<...>` which correctly propagates associated executors/allocators again. I would dub this kind of type a "handler binder"

### LIVE DEMO

To illustrate the reality that `system_executor` is being used, here's a simplified tester:

**[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5nP1nYbKj)**

```
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::asio;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    io_context ctx(1);

    spawn([](yield_context yield) {
        std::cout << "started spawn" << std::endl;

        auto ex = get_associated_executor(yield);
        //auto work = make_work_guard(ex);

        steady_timer timer(ex, 5s);
        timer.async_wait(yield);

        std::cout << "finished spawn" << std::endl;
    });

    std::cout << "running context" << std::endl;
    query(system_executor{}, execution::context).join();
    std::cout << "finished running context" << std::endl;
}
```

Notes:

- `ctx` now takes a concurrency hint (as mentioned above)
- `ctx` is **never used**; joining it would *not* wait for coro to be completed!
- Note the commented `work`. It is important that though async operations constitute work, the [Coro itself is not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26728121/85371) so you might want to guard the scope of the coro in some situations.
- Note that `system_executor` is joined like you would another thread-based execution context like `thread_pool`:

  ```
   query(system_executor{}, execution::context).join();
  ```

Now it prints

```
started spawn
running context
finished spawn
finished running context
```

with the 5s delay as expected.

Comment: Clarified the theory by making your sample into a _working_ **[sample](https://godbolt.org/z/GMPbsn)** with some annotations

Comment: Is `ctx` in the notes the same object as  `io_context` in the code snippet?

Comment: @sbabbi Yeah. Sorry. I forgot I updated that name after I copied the code. Fixed.